# JasperReports, PrintWhenExpression and RemoveLineWhenBlank → Strange Behaviour

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a problem with JasperReports when using printWhenExpression and RemoveWhenBlank inside a subreport.

To reproduce this problem, I made a simple example using one master report and two subreport.
The first subreport, let's call it the static subreport, contains two Static Text components in the title band (Label 1 on the first line, Label 3 on the second), both have the Position Type attribute set to Float. The title band Split Type attribute is set to "Immediate".

The dynamic subreport have three Static text components (Label 1 on the 1st line, Label 2 on the second and Label 3 on the third), all of them have the Position Type set to Float. But Label 2 has PrintWhenExpression set to Boolean.FALSE and RemoveLineWhenBlank set to TRUE. So Label 2 is hidden and Label 3 is moved to Label 2's place under Label 1.

So basically the dynamic subreport and the static one have the same structure and should behave the same way when printed inside a report. But that's not the case in this little example.

In the master report I'm using a subreport component inside the detail band ( the split type of the detail band is set to Immediate ) and using a JREmptyDataSource with 90 empty rows. When pointing the subreport component to the static subreport, the pdf output generated by jasperreports is corrrect. But when using the dynamic subreport, jasperreports leaves an empty space (that is used when using the static subreport) at the end of the first page and jumps to the next page to print Label 3.

In the real case that I have a problem with, I have a subreport that contains more than 20 lines with Static Text and Text Field components, most to them with printWhenExpression set to a field or a parameter and RemoveLineWhenBlank set to TRUE. When producing the pdf output in some cases I have that specific subreport (which should occupy just  a third of a page) spanning one page and a half with a lot of space spread between the visible lines in the subreport. And I think the combination of RemoveLineWenBlank and PrintWhenExpression is what's causing the problem.
 
So what I want know is if this is a bug or just me missing something in the documentation.
Here is a link to the post I made at the JasperReports forum, it contains the templates for the master report and the two subreports, plus two pdfs generated by jasperreports  and screenshots showing the layout of the subreports: [link](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=90196)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've just used printWhenExpression with my report templates and that seems to work fine on its own. Have you tried just using 1 flag at a time and seeing what happens?